# boundedness of a function in complex space

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

locate the singularity and tell whether it is removable, a pole, or essential:

$$\frac{e^z - 1}{z}$$

so I know the singularity is at 0, but how can I determine what kind of singulairty? For it to be a removable singularity the magnitude of my function |f(z)| < (infiniti)  now the solution says it is removable, but I can't figure out how to find it.

Comment: Consider the Taylor series for $e^z$

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Try the Laurent series expansion of $e^z$. What is the first term? What happens when you subtract 1 and divide by $z$?

Comment: after I subtract by one and divide by z the laurent series expansion is:    $$\\1 + \frac{z}{2!} + \frac{z^2}{3!} + \frac{z^3}{4!}.......$$                not seeing how that helps......unless it is fair to say factorials expand faster than powers.........

Comment: I also had a similar question with regards to finding the Laurent series to a question very similar to this except for $$z^2$$ in the denominator instead. It has to do with the region I'm solving on. In this instance we would say there is a pole at z = 0, so wouldn't this mean that my function is only analytic on the disc r < |z-z0| ?  where r = 0?  Which would mean that my laurent series should be of the form:  $$\sum_{-\infty}^{0} a_k (z-z_0)^-k  $$    that k is supposed to be in the exponent

Answer (score 2):

$\lim_{z\to 0} \,(e^z-1)/z$ is the derivative of $e^z$ at $0.$

Answer (score 0):

It is a removable singularity, since $f(z)=e^z-1$ is an entire function satisfying:
$$ f(z)=e^z-1 = z+\frac{z^2}{2!}+\frac{z^3}{3!}+\ldots $$
so that $z=0$ is a simple zero for $f(z)$ and:
$$ \frac{f(z)}{z} = 1+\frac{z}{2!}+\frac{z^2}{3!}+\ldots $$
is an entire function, too.